# Monotouch: Automating the bindings?

Tags: .net, objective-c, binding, mono, xamarin.ios

I have a Objective-C assembly, "SomeThing.a"

Is there a way to automatically generate the MonoTouch binding c# and or .dll for this assembly?

I do not have the source code for the "something.a"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the associated header file for it, you can try using the MonoMac parser that does some of the heavy lifting for you and generates a starting point for your binding.

The parser is in monomac/src/parser.cs

Run it like this:

gmcs parser.cs
mono parser.exe yourHeader.h

It will generate the file "gen.cs" that contains the parsed header file.

If you have no source code for the .a file and you still want to bind some of the APIs, you can get an idea of what is in this class using ClassDump:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ClassDump

Comment: Does this still exist? I can't find parser.cs on my system... I am using Xamarin.Mac, not MonoMac

Comment: @lordscarlet I'm not sure that this is the same parser that Miguel mentioned, but: http://www.kevfoo.com/2011/09/monotouch_bindings/